# How to properly send an Ajax Post request for creating fusion tables using google OAuth2?

Tags: ajax, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to create a fusion table using the documentation provided by Google fusion table REST API https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/using. 
I am sending an ajax request in the following format

`$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                crossDomain: true,
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/tables",
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", token);
                },
                data: { 
                    access_token: token,
                     "name": "Insects",
                     "columns": [
                      {
                       "name": "Species",
                       "type": "STRING"
                      },
                      {
                       "name": "Elevation",
                       "type": "NUMBER"
                      },
                      {
                       "name": "Year",
                       "type": "DATETIME"
                      }
                     ],
                     "description": "Insect Tracking Information.",
                     "isExportable": true
                 },
                 async: false,
                 success: function(result){
                    alert(result);
                },
            error: function(result) {
              alert('error');
            }
        });`

But I am getting a 401 error. I tried setting Bearer , token in the authorization header but still no success.Any pointers will be much appreciated.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue with:

```
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+ token);
```